# How do I force Razor to check validation on TextBox in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, validation, razor

I have a field called ACTIVITY_NAME which I have defined as such:

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Acitivity Name is Required.")]
[StringLength(255)]
    public string ACTIVITY_NAME { get; set; }
```

I setup my textbox to render it front-end like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EditActivity.ACTIVITY_NAME, new { @id = "ActivityName", @class = "width400", placeholder = Localization.ActivityName })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EditActivity.ACTIVITY_NAME)
```

When the form is submited, the following JS handler is fired:

```
    $('#AddTaskActivity').click(function (evt) {
        $('#activityModal').modal('hide');
        evt.preventDefault();
        var formData = $('#ActivityForm').serialize();
        CreateActivity(formData);
    });
```

So basically, this would prevent the default handler, and the validation would not fire.  I didn't write this code, but I would like to add validation.  How do I force fire the validation in the handler before it post to server?

Comment: You have to do a fake submit form for validation triggers.

Comment: I can't just call the validation client side?

Comment: Client side validation will activate only when you try to submit the form.

Comment: Right, and I would like force that validation before submitting.

Comment: Are you submitting the form via Ajax?

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to trigger the validation manually in the handler above? Can you do $('#ActivityForm').validate(); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better way, but this is how I trigger client side validation before submitting the form. They must be called before submitting the form.

```
// For non Ajax forms
function ValidateHtml5(event) {
    event = event || window.event || event.srcElement;

    var form = $(event.target);

    if (form[0].checkValidity()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('<input type="submit">').hide().appendTo(form[0]).click().remove(); // trigger
        return false;
    }
}

// For Ajax form validation
function ValidateHtml5Ajax(form) {
    if (form.checkValidity()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $('<input type="submit">').hide().appendTo(form).click().remove(); // trigger
        return false;
    }
}
```